# Como copiar o texto selecionado para o clipboard usando firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, área-de-transferência, extensão, firefox-extensão

Preciso, após selecionar um texto em qualquer página web, que eu copie esse texto, enviando o texto para outra função, que fará posterior "post".

O problema é que preciso remover a seleção após copiar o texto, sendo assim o método "getselection", ao remover o range, retorna vazio.

A solução anterior era usar execcomand e enviar para o clipboard e retornar o texto. Porém isso só funciona no Chrome, não no Firefox que é meu foco atual. Alguma sugestão ou ajuda?

Comment: Seu problema então não é copiar, e sim remover a seleção?

Comment: repensei e cheguei a conclusão de que sim! Uma simples simulação de clique do mouse serviria, certo? Porque ao fazer o post, não interessa mais o texto selecionado pois está tudo no servidor, correto?